# Which Smalltalk flavors support writing C code in a method?

Tags: c, smalltalk, primitive

I've heard that in Smalltalk/X and possibly other flavors you can include C code inside a method, is this possible with other Smalltalk implementations? which ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smalltalk/X is the only Smalltalk I am aware of that supports writing C code directly within Smalltalk methods. Of course, most other Smalltalks (Pharo, VisualWorks, GemStone, ...) allow you to write and use primitive methods written in C, but this is rather cumbersome and requires one to use an external C compiler.

An interesting alternative could be [NativeBoost](http://code.google.com/p/nativeboost/), a library to dynamically generate and run machine code from within Pharo.

Comment: +1 for NativeBoost (which also, last I checked, ran just fine in Squeak too).